# Multipart/form-data file upload in asp.net core web api

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

How to do Multipart-form-data file upload in asp.net core web api? Is it possible to POST both JSON and the image at the same time in a single POST?

Answer (score 18):

**Update- .net core 2.0 +**

With **.net core** you can leverage the new `IFormFile` interface to upload both the image and properties in the same post. For example:

```cs
[HttpPost("content/upload-image")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(MyFile upload)
```

The MyFile class can look like:

```cs
public class MyFile
{
    public string userId { get; set; }        
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

You can access the `properties` and the `file` as follows:

```cs
var file = upload.File // This is the IFormFile file
var param = upload.userId // param
```

To persist/save the file to disk you can do the following:

```cs
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    await file.File.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
```

**.NET Framework**

Yes it is. Depending on the client **Framework** you're using, you can configure your **Web API** for **Content Type-Multipart**, then do something like:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("content/upload-image")]       
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }           
    // enter code here
}
```

Define and setup the directory where your image will be saved.

```cs
var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/");
if (!Directory.Exists(root))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
}
```

Setup the StreamProvider and attempt to get the **model** data, which is the **JSON** you mentioned.

```cs
var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
var result =
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
if (result.FormData["model"] == null)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

Now access the files in the request.

```cs
try
{
    // Deserialize model data to your own DTO
    var model = result.FormData["model"];
    var formDto = JsonConvert
        .DeserializeObject<MyDto>(model, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
    var files = result.FileData.ToList();                
    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            // Do anything with the file(s)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try out the solution.

Comment: I am not able to access Request.Content in .net core 2.0 preview. Any idea on that?

Comment: `IFormFile` interface was introduce in .net core. Have a look at it here:


 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As far as i know, IFormFile interface is for MVC application not for WebApi.

Comment: This example is not for dotnet core

Comment: I added a .net core implementation.

Comment: I think you need [FromForm] attribute also

Comment: For me on .NET Core 3.1 it only worked after adding `[FromForm]` in the method argument list  as @ManuMohanThekkedath suggested.